# Magento 2 locale issue

Tags: magento2, localisation

I have install [en_GB](https://github.com/bnspayments/magento2-language-en-gb) locale and deployed content with both:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB

I've also cleared cache and did:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

When inspected the code in frontend. I found that data is coming from

> pub/static/magento/frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB

However, frontend shows french locale. Is there anything else that i can do ?

Comment: Have you changed the locale in Magento admin?
`Stores -> Configuration -> General -> General -> Locale`

Comment: @Radosav Yes i have changed.

Comment: Try using: `php bin/magento setup:store-config:set --language=en_GB` And clearing cache, re-deploy..etc

Comment: @Radosav tried this way but no luck.

Comment: @Radosav I think its a french pack that's why its showing french in frontend. I found french content in csv files when i tried checking csv files.